# for loop execute only once

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, infinite-loop

Code only executes once.
Disclaimer: Well aware this is an infinite loop, wrote it this way as part of troubleshooting the problem.

update: There was an exception in my error log that got fixed and the problem is still the same, code only executes once
I tried using the same `for` loop in the same code for a different task (printing a sentence) and it worked fine, problem must be with my JS code.

```java
for(int i=0; i<i+1;i++) {
    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.open()"); 
    ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles()); 
    driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
    driver.get("https://www.google.com");
}
```

Comment: @YCF_L That is not true, if you replace the contents of the for-loop with just a print(i) statement it will not stop in 1 iteration.

Comment: Why is there a comma in `"https://www,google.com"`?

Comment: I know this. As I mentioned, I know it is an infinite loop. Moreover, it still get executed only once even when it is something like:  ```for(int i+0; i<10; i++)```

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Mistake on my part when formatting this here, thank you for pointing it out, I fixed it.

Comment: @Sergio Is it throwing an exception? Maybe you catch it somewhere but don't log anything? (Assuming you checked the logs.)

Comment: Are you sure driver.get() isn't a blocking operation? (it waits before continuing)

Comment: @Ivar no error, execution ends normally, just without execution the content of the ```for loop``` multiple times.

Comment: @Frontear yes, used it before, in the same program and different programs.

Comment: I guess this discussion is going nowhere. We need an [mre].

Comment: @second there is already 1 tab open at this point in the program and the commands in the for loop create another one, which totals to 2 (can see them in front of me as well, this is a browser automation tool).

Comment: @Sergio: You already stated the behaviour is the same if you replace the for loop with `while(true)` so there must be some kind of exception/error.

Comment: @Sergio Unless I forgot something, there are four ways to exit a for-loop: The termination condition evaluate to `false`, a `break` is called, `return` is called, or an exception is thrown. The first three don't apply here (if this is the actual code you are using) so as far as I can see an exception is the only possibility.

Comment: I just found something while digging.

Comment: @second https://imgur.com/bowxjKx

Comment: Try to wrap the whole thing a in `try { ... } catch (Throwable t) { t.printStackTrace(); }` and tell us the output.

Comment: @second can you show me the exact piece of code you want me to execute? sorry it is not clear and I am still new to this so I need more clarification to understand.

Comment: @second can you explain?

Comment: You're saying it now does not terminate? If thats the case maybe your plugin-errors stopped eclipse from compiling your code, and you run some other code instead.

Comment: yes it keeps on running as intended now, is there a permanent fix?

Comment: I'll guess your problem is related to the IDE (eclipse). Try fixing the error's from the screenshot or startover with a fresh eclipes installation. Or hope that this will never happen again ;) -- Your original code should work as well in that case.

Comment: @second thank you! I will try

Comment: You might want to delete the question yourself. Its unlikely to be of help to anybody else.

Comment: @second, thought I'd give a little update. Fixed the error, it was due to a missing connector. Still same problem wit the loop, sometimes the try-catch code fixes it and other times no. weird.

Comment: nothing in error log now though

Comment: tried marking the other lines as a comment so they do not execute while adding a print command and it all executed, problem must be with the code in my loop.

Answer (score 1):

Code is executing only once because of an exception being thrown, OR maybe one or more of the network calls you are making is taking too long that makes you believe that the code is executing only once.

To confirm that the value `i + 1`, which you are using in the for-loop isn't getting replaced by `1`, I ran the following loop on my machine:

```
for (int i = 0; i < i + 1; i++) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

...and it goes on to print numbers starting from 0.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to clarify this point as an answer, as I expect the question will be removed.

The for loop isn't your problem. You are writing code which has an exception or is blocking the running thread. If you're using another thread to run this, a lack of an `UncaughtExceptionHandler` can allow it to skip being logged. Similarly the use of `Callable<T>` can result in exceptions being swallowed from personal experience (perhaps for the same reason?).

If you are blocking the thread running it, then that thread won't run *anything* else until the blocking method returns control to the context of where you called it.

Given you said you had cases where the loop "ran once" but still printed after, I'm going to go with it being an exception, and the way that you are running your test is flawed. This can be from an uncountable number of reasons, such as a folly `System#exit`/`Runtime#halt` call, threads, using a service to run the tests, or running them in some production environment like a game server or a phone (or... A browser?). For future cases, your questions should ideally be reproducible with nothing other than a main method and the code you provide. If you cannot make such an example, at minimum you should provide *how* you are testing it.

If you do all of that and still have the issue, I think it will either be obvious to you, or the people reading your question here will have a much easier time answering it for you.